# How do you add a bevel modifier to this head

Tags: modifiers

I want to add bevel to the head in [this rig](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/244331196/D57RigV1.61.blend)(a minecraft rig).
Whenever I try to add the bevel it has texture glitches and crashes when I move the mouth. The mouth is a boolean mouth and that is where most of the glitches are.

Comment: Beveling it in edit mode worked fine for me.

Comment: @PGmath i want it to bevel the mouth as well and that is a boolean mouth

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a boolean?  Why not just extrude the mouth inwards?

Comment: From my experience boolean operations, in theory, are a great tool.  But in reality they cause a lot of problems.  The biggest problem I have found is that, even if they work "properly", they create *terrible* topology.

Comment: @PGmath boolean mouth is a style of mouth for minecraft rigs which does not have texture deformation. plus i also forgot to mention, i have a driver to turn on and off the bevel. also the eyes have wired texture glitches as well